# Which one is faster ! or == operation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, logic, compiler-optimization, logical-operators

I wanted to know if there is any difference in performance upon using `!` operator in place of `==` operator.

This is my understanding and please correct me if I am wrong.

`!` operator - does inverts all the bits and for integer it goes over 32 bits for flipping all the bits. works with one operand and maps to `not` operator in assembly code.

`==` operator - works with two operand and involves `CMP` and eventually `JMP` operation in assembly which is costly.

For a simple statement like the following which one performs better?

```
function(){
   return (some operation) == 0
}
```

or

```
function(){
   return !(some operation)
}
```

#### Languages: C++, Java, Python

#### platform: linux

Comment: What language and platform?  Both are exactly one instruction on x86, MIPS and 68000 where it'd always be a `jne {reg},0` (or `je {reg},0`) or platform equivilient.

Comment: Pretty sure that while there are several ways to implement, most compilers already reduce these operations to minimal machine code.

Comment: For c++ you can always check it yourself under different compilers at Gotbolt.org, eg https://godbolt.org/z/q3FQC6
In the linked case both ways compile to exactly same set of instructions.

Comment: The `!` operator doesn't invert the bits. The `!` operator changes 0 to 1, and any non-zero value to 0.  The `~` operator inverts the bits.